# Ribbon form. Image object. How to programmatically set the path to the picture in the form element "picture"?

Tags: ms-access, vba

The combox `cmb_pic_name` is filled with the data from the `directory_Pic` with the query:

```
SELECT [directory_Pic].pic_name, [directory_Pic].pic_path FROM directory_Pic;
```

The user selects the name of the image from the combox `cmb_pic_name`.
Acces displays the image in the `frm_Image` (Image object) element.
 
I try to do with the code:

```
Private Sub cmb_pic_name_AfterUpdate()
     Me.frm_Image.Picture = cmb_pic_name.Column(1)
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()    
      frm_Image.Picture = cmb_pic_name.Column(1)
End Sub
```

Does not work.
 
**Question:** how to programmatically set the path to the picture in the form element "picture"?

[image]
[image]
[image]

**Update_1**
Register for the link that is specified in the `Gustav` solution.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

In a single-record form it would work, but your picture control is unbound, thus - in a continuous form - it will display the same picture for all records.

Make the picture control bound to `pic_path`.

An example for this - though for downloadable pictures - can be found in my article:

[Show pictures directly from URLs in Access forms and reports](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/29679/Show-pictures-directly-from-URLs-in-Access-forms-and-reports.html)

As you'll see, for each record it retrieves the path to the picture.

Click the link:

[image]

**Click here to view the full article**

Comment: Sorry, but I can not get full access to the article and therefore I see only part of the article.
Do you suggest in the table `Table_1` to make a separate field` pic_path` in which to store the path to the picture of each record?

Comment: To get access, just find the link "Read the full article" or similar somewhere down the page.

Comment: **1.** Site requires registration. Registration on the site is paid. When registering a free period, card entry required. I do not want to enter my card details. I'll think about it.
If you have other sources where your article is posted, I will be grateful if you share it. [link](https://i.ibb.co/gSLVMXb/2019-04-22-16-34-20.png) **2.** Do you suggest in the table `Table_1` to make a separate field `pic_path` in which to store the path to the picture of each record?

Comment: Updated the question.
See `Update_1`.